# Large Integer ID matching

Tags: python, numpy, match

I have a ten digit ID for my target, meanwhile I have a bunch of ID's for my potential pairs with the target. The ID for the potential pairs is either -1 if they are not a pair or the target ID if they are a pair. For example,

```
 ID_target = 1234567890
 ID_potential = np.array([-1, -1, 1234567890, -1, -1, 1234567890, -1, 1234567890, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

We can easily tell that there are three pairs. However, how to find the pairs and return the index of the pairs? I tried the following but failed:

```
 np.where(ID_potential == ID_target)
```

It should return the following index:

```
 pair_index = [2,5,7]
```

I also do not quite understand the above command does not do the correct thing.

Comment: `np.flatnonzero(ID_potential == ID_target)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for your comment, I tried this command, but it returned some error, which says `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ravel'`.

Comment: Huh... what about `np.argwhere(ID_potential == ID_target).ravel()`?

Comment: Is `ID_potential` actually a numpy array? Try `np.where(np.array(ID_potential) == ID_target)`...

Comment: I think the reason you're getting that AttributeError is that the list just compares with the integer to give `False`, and then you're trying to create a flattened array out of `False`, which is impossible.

Comment: A variation of @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ solution: `np.flatnonzero(np.array(ID_potential) == ID_target).tolist()`

Comment: I already convert the `ID_potential` to numpy array, it returns index of [2,5] but not 7. I would say `np.where( = )` method is not safe. Because in my real data, the `np.where( = )` does not return any correct index of the pairs.

Comment: Are your "real data" integers or floats or even strings? You should print the type of the actual `ID_potential` arrays in your code.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what it *does* return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @COLDSPEED comment. Changed conversion of `ID_potential` to `numpy` array:

```
>>> np.flatnonzero(np.asarray(ID_potential) == ID_target).tolist()
[2, 5, 7]
```

Another version:

```
>>> np.where(np.equal(ID_potential, ID_target))[0].tolist()
```

If this does not work in your actual code, then most likely there is a type mismatch between `ID_potential` and `ID_target` in your actual code/data or some of the data are floating point and therefore strict equality may not hold. In that case use `numpy.isclose()`.

Just to make the code more resilient to mistakes, try this version:

```
np.where(np.equal(np.asarray(ID_potential, dtype=np.int), np.int(ID_target)))[0].tolist()
```

or, if the values are actually `float` - replace `np.int` above with `np.float` and `np.equal` with `np.isclose()`:

```
np.where(np.isclose(np.asarray(ID_potential, dtype=np.float), np.float(ID_target)))[0].tolist()
```

Comment: @HuanianZhang Which version did work for you? Where was the actual problem?